# How to simplify this vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This is from the book G.E. Hay Vector and Tensor Calculus page 18. Please see the blue arrow I marked on the image, I don't see what the book did to get from the left-hand side to the right-hand side. Can someone please explain? This is the only step I haven't understood. Thanks!

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yio33.png)

Edit: Thanks a lot for all the input! I understood my question. Sorry for posting an image, next time I'll try to post the proper way. Also sorry for not mentioning the theorem referenced in the text but I didn't talk about it because I looked it up and there was none apparently.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Continuing Jose's comment, you should also mention what have you tried to tackle this problem. It will not attract downvotes and prevent the question from being closed.

Comment: In the figure you have shared, it is written that Theorem 1 of section 9 gives the simplification. Have you gone through it?

Comment: Did you look at the theorem the text refers to?

Comment: Does the referenced theorem look somewhat like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Properties?

Answer (score 0):

The formula  only says that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}\cdot(\mathbf{c}\times\mathbf{d})=\mathbf{c}\cdot(\mathbf{d}\times\mathbf{x})
\end{align}
for all vectors $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{c},\mathbf{d}$. And this is easy to show by using the definition of vector product through the Levi-Civita symbol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol):
\begin{align}
\varepsilon_{ijk}c_id_jx_k=\varepsilon_{ijk}d_ix_jc_k\underbrace{=}_{\text{change 
 indices}}\varepsilon_{kij}c_id_jx_k
\end{align}
i.e. you only need to show that $\varepsilon_{ijk}=\varepsilon_{kij}$, which is true from its definition.